# Count dropdown menu items

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, c#

In my case, I choose a file and I open the drop-down menu.

In the drop-down menu are three actions:

1. Add tag
2. Remove tag
3. Lock document

I use "Lock document" action and after that if I choose the same file and open the menu,
the action Lock document will disappear.

Questions:

1. how to determine the count of actions in the menu?
2. how to verify if action "Lock document" disappeared ?

Comment: Is the dropdown a `<select>` element with dropdown menu as `<option>` elements or a custom element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Java developer, but I'll give C# a try as well:

1. how to determine the count of actions in the menu?

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(locator);
SelectElement selectList = new SelectElement(elem);
IList options = selectList.Options;
int count = options.Count;
```

2. how to verify if action "Lock document" disappeared ?

```
bool containsLockDoc = false;
foreach (IWebElement option in options)
{
    string actual = option.Text();
    string expected = "Lock document";
    containsLockDoc = actual.Equals(expected);
    if(containsLockDoc) {
        break; // Lock Document exists in the dropdown options list
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with this error ?

Comment: It works.
I changed this line: containsLockDoc = actual.Contains(expected);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for menu:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li role="presentation">
<li role="presentation">
<li class="mlck divider" role="presentation"/>
<li class="mlck" role="presentation">
<li class="divider" role="presentation"/>
<li role="presentation">
<li class="divider" role="presentation"/>
<li role="presentation">
<a onclick="tagl(); return false;" tabindex="6" role="menuitemradio">Lock document</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
<li class="mlck divider" role="presentation"/>
<li class="mlck" role="presentation">
</ul>
```

I used this code:

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(apath));
            SelectElement selectList = new SelectElement(elem);
            IList<IWebElement> options = selectList.Options;

            bool containsLockDoc = false;
            foreach (IWebElement option in options)
            {
                string actual = option.Text;
                string expected = "Lock document";
                containsLockDoc = actual.Equals(expected);
                if (containsLockDoc)
                {
                    break; // Lock Document exists in the dropdown options list
                }
            }
```

And I got error:

OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been select but was ul

Comment: Can anybody help me with this error ?